# ORA-00904: "CTN_QUANTITY": - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, count, alias

I try to select rows where CTN_QUANTITY is not empty. My query

```
select distinct SDB.CTN_MAIN as S_CTN_MAIN, 
    SDB.SUBS_KEY as S_SUBS_KEY, 
    SDB.BAN_KEY as S_BAN_KEY, 
    count(SDB.CTN_MAIN) as CTN_QUANTITY,
    FPCN.BAN_KEY as BAN_KEY
from STG_SDB_LOAD SDB, FCT_PREP_CHARGES_N FPCN
    where FPCN.business_service_key = 33006
    and CTN_QUANTITY <> ''
group by SDB.CTN_MAIN, 
    SDB.SUBS_KEY, 
    SDB.BAN_KEY, 
    FPCN.BAN_KEY;
```

I get error

```
ORA-00904. -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `IS NOT NULL` in place of <> . Also you cannot use alias in `and` clause.

```
 select a.* from 
  (SELECT DISTINCT SDB.CTN_MAIN AS S_CTN_MAIN,
                  SDB.SUBS_KEY AS S_SUBS_KEY,
                  SDB.BAN_KEY AS S_BAN_KEY,
                  COUNT (SDB.CTN_MAIN) AS CTN_QUANTITY,
                  FPCN.BAN_KEY AS BAN_KEY
    FROM STG_SDB_LOAD SDB, FCT_PREP_CHARGES_N FPCN
   WHERE FPCN.business_service_key = 33006   
GROUP BY SDB.CTN_MAIN,
         SDB.SUBS_KEY,
         SDB.BAN_KEY,
         FPCN.BAN_KEY ) a
 WHERE a.CTN_QUANTITY IS NOT NULL
```

Things to analyze : Is it really useful to have such condition   `a.CTN_QUANTITY IS NOT NULL`. May be you can learn more by reseraching on this and considering `@mathguy` suggestion.

Comment: Already tried it.  and CTN_QUANTITY is not null. does not work either.

Comment: Read updated answer. Also since you are groupin the result, there is no need for distinct.

Comment: @EugeneCuz - Are you sure this is the desired solution? (Probably, since you marked this as the Correct Answer.) I will say it again, I said it in my Answer as well:  a COUNT can NEVER BE NULL, so this condition may as well be removed altogether. What you MAY want instead is to check if the count is not equal to ZERO (not "NOT NULL").

Comment: @mathguy..I know you voted -1 to question and my answer. Bt you always forget one thing that you always cannot be the boss. You give some space to OP to analyse his stuff and correct them wherever he is wrong. Thats the reason +1 voted to OP and -1 for your attitude.

Comment: @XING - of course, you are free to do as you please (although in general votes are for the quality of questions and answers, not for the quality of posters and their attitude). Such is the nature of SO. In your case: I didn't downvote your first version where you still had an alias in the WHERE condition, you fixed that. You fixed a few more things. I gave you enough time to fix COUNT IS NOT NULL, but you didn't even after I pointed that out in my answer. After I thought enough time had passed, I downvoted your answer for that reason. It has nothing to do with being boss, but with your answer.

Comment: @mathguy.your down vote is not going to stop me from what i wanted to communicate. I just gave some scope for the OP to understand what he did and where is might have done wrong. I have seen your comments on many post which is neither professional nor ethical and I refrain myself from such post when you gave answers.

Comment: @XING - that is so wrong! Comments on other people's answers (mine included!!) are a very important part of what we are doing here. The point is to get the right answers in the end, not to "avoid making someone feel bad about what they posted." And votes are used to indicate good and bad answers. What is unprofessional or unethical about that? I don't think I ever posted judgments on a person's qualification or intellect - THAT would be unprofessional and unethical. Judging the correctness of one's code is 100% what this is about.

Answer (score 3):

`CTN_QUANTITY` is defined as the alias for an expression in the `SELECT` clause. But you want to use it in the `WHERE` clause. That will not work - `WHERE` is processed before `SELECT`. You will have to use `count(SDB.CTN_MAIN)` in the `WHERE` clause, not its alias.

Then: The count is always a number, but you are comparing it to the empty string. Which in Oracle is `NULL`, but regardless, it doesn't make sense. And, the `COUNT` may be zero, it should never be `NULL`.

You probably need to write `WHERE count(....) <> 0`.

**Edit**: And, of course, as discussed in Comments below... a COUNT filter does not belong in the WHERE clause, it should be in a HAVING clause.

Comment: I tried using count(SDB.CTN_MAIN) too. but got "group function is not allowed here".

Comment: Right. We are solving the problems one by one - this deals with the question you posted. Now: The condition on `COUNT` should go in a `HAVING` condition, not in a `WHERE` condition. You may find even more errors - you already had four so far. Who knows. Anyway, if you have different questions, you should ask them in separate posts.